# LibGDX: Camera lerp shakes when approaching target

Tags: libgdx, viewport, orthographic, linear-interpolation, lerp

I am using an Orthographic camera using a ScreenViewport with "UnitsPerPixel" set to 0.333f and when I move the play and then stop, the camera catches up as expected but then starts shaking slightly and acting weird when getting close (around the last few pixels). I am just using the basic lerp:
`cam.position.lerp(new Vector3(entityToFocusOn.getLocation().getX() + ArchipeloClient.PLAYER_SIZE / 2, entityToFocusOn.getLocation().getY() + ArchipeloClient.PLAYER_SIZE / 2, 0), deltatime);`

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Another one:

[image]

Overall, not very smooth.

P.S. Often it is much worse than in that gif.

Comment: Round your character position to nearest integer when drawing.

Comment: That solved the issue of the player slightly moving around, but did not fix the camera shake issue, It does look a bit better though. Thanks.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That wouldn't fix it because the lerp itself is not rounded to the nearest integer...that's why it's shaking.

Comment: @Hasan it fixes the character being out of sync with the surroundings, but you’re right. The camera position also needs to be rounded to the nearest multiple of in-game pixel size after lerping.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are interpolating between the camera position and the player position indefinitely. A quick way to fix this is to set a threshold for the camera to snap to the player.

So `if distance is less than x then snap to player position and stop lerping`.  This way its not doing tiny micro movements.

Another solution can be to round out your camera position after you have lerped it so that its in screen units. Sometimes this could be as simple as rounding to the nearest integer but other times You have to take scaling into account.

Comment: I ended up removing the lerping altogether, but I recall trying this solution and the "snapping" was always noticeable, even if the epsilon test distance was short.

Comment: That doesn't work to solve the problem. If you have the snap to player too early it looks really artificial, but if you have to any later than that it still wobbles about. The issue is that the lerp itself is not rounded to exact pixels....but there doesn't seem to be any way to fix that.